# MOD_REWRITE is not behaving as expected

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

This doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)([/]?)$ /index.cgi?l=$1 [NC,L]
```

This doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.cgi?l=$1 [NC,L]
```

There's no other rules in the .htaccess file. Here's the complete version:

```
Options -Indexes
Options ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .q
ErrorDocument 500 /error500.cgi
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.cgi
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.cgi?l=$1 [NC,L]
```

This DOES work, but it's not what I want.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.cgi?l=$1&a=$2 [NC,L]
```

I want both the first slash and second directory to be optional. Why won't the question mark match 0 or 1 instances like it's supposed to? I am freaking here...

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Start at the beginning and explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to pass 'directory' names to a CGI script as variables. But the second 'directory' may or may not be requested as with the preceding forward-slash.

Answer (score 0):

By using a `$`, you're specifying that it's the end of the text, so that won't match anything after a `/`. (in regex, `^` specifies the beginning of a string and `$` specifies the end)

You could remove the `$`, then it will make the second parameter optional - that sounds like what you're looking for.

Try this to see if your mod_rewrite is working correctly:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: `code`RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?([a-z]+)? /index.cgi?l=$1&a=$2 [NC,L]`code`

Produces the following Apache error page:
Found

The document has moved here. [same link as requested]
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/1.3.37 Server at www.mysite.org Port 80

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if the `$` is required. So try this: `RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/?(.+)?$` That should give you the contents of the first /.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. This time I set the R flag so it redirects and I can see where it's going and this is URL I got (brace yourself):
http://www.mysite.org/index.cgi?l=http:&a=/www.mysite.org/

It's testing the entire URL??

Comment: Hmm, that's very unusual behavior.
Try something simple, like this to see if your mod_rewrite is working correctly: ... adding to my answer, since comments can't be formatted.

Comment: That's what I thought! I've been battling with MOD_REWRITE for the last few days and been getting totally unexpected results and errors all the time. Either I'm thick as two planks or the module is completely counter intuitive or there's something funny about my server software!! Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Did you get the same results with the example in my post? If mod_rewrite is working correctly, it shouldn't give you the full URL. There may be a setting in apache that would need to be changed, unfortunately, my mod_rewrite has always given the expected results.

Comment: Thanks, I solved this. There was a greedy (.*) in another rule that was gobbling all in its path. Thanks again!